# Delete rows in one table based upon information in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete my rows from Table2, where the ID exists in Table1, and in Table1 the value determining if a deletion should occur resides.

Example:

Table1

```
+--------+--------+
|   ID   | Author |
+--------+--------+
|  121   |  John  |
+--------+--------+
|  150   |  Ann   |
+--------+--------+
```

Table2

```
+--------+---------+-----------+
|   ID   | MetaKey | MetaValue |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|  121   |  Color  |    red    |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|  150   |  Color  |    grey   |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|  121   |  Weight |    10     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
|  150   |  Weight |    30     |
+--------+---------+-----------+
```

And delete rows from Table2, which's Author is 'John' (from Table1)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with an `exists` clause and a correlated subquery:

```
delete from t2
where exists (select 1 from t1 where t2.id = t1.id and t1.Author = 'John')
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, which performs better?  Joining or exists subquery?

Comment: @MushinNoShin . . . If you have an index on `t1(id, Author)` then both should perform about the same.  If `t1` has multiple matches for a given `id`, then the `exists` should perform better.  This is standard SQL.  The `delete` with `join` syntax is not available in all databases.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete table2
from table2
inner join table1 on table1.ID = table2.ID
where table1.author = 'John'
```